# How can I fix the problem with gets() function in C?

Tags: c, string, gets

There is a problem with `gets` function. The first `gets` I write does not work but the ones comes next works properly.

I put an extra `gets()` function at the beginning, program just skips it and gets the string I want. But it is not safe and reliable. So what is the problem with gets and how can I fix it?

```
if (choice == 1) {
  printf("Please enter an English phrase with upper case: ");
  gets(a);
  gets(engphr);
  for (i = 0; engphr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

Comment: I guess you use `scanf` before this code and the new line char will remain in the inputt buffer which your first `gets` will eat so the code will work as expected. Hard to say for sure tho without the whole code.

Comment: You cannot fix the problem with `gets()`. `gets()` is unfixable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem, and the exact input you are giving. Also please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) You should be using `fgets` instead, `gets` is no longer a standard C function, and is only recognised by compilers for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eraklon mentions in their comment, the most likely cause is that you have a `scanf` call before the `gets` call, and the trailing newline from the previous input is getting consumed by `gets` before you have a chance to enter anything else.

You should never use `gets` anyway - it was removed from the standard library in the 2011 version of the language.  It is inherently unsafe to use, and *will* introduce a security hole in your code.  Use `fgets` instead.  Its behavior is slightly different (it will save the trailing newline to the input buffer if there's room, where `gets` discarded it), but it's much safer:

```
if ( fgets( engphr, sizeof engphr, stdin ) ) // assumes engphr is declared as an array, not a pointer
{
  // process engphr
}
```

Having said that, you really shouldn't mix calls to `scanf` and `fgets`, again because `scanf` will leave trailing newlines in the input stream from previous inputs, and `fgets` will immediately return after seeing that newline.  Either read all input using `fgets` and use `sscanf` to read specific items from the input buffer, or read all input with `scanf`.

Comment: I did use scanf() before gets() to take the value of 'choice'. I will try to use fgets and make it work. Thank you so much for your help.